# Forced to redirect in controller when setting cache object in cakephp 2.5

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, redirect, memcached

I have a Categories controller in my CakePHP 2.5 project that queries an external, third-party API to get a result of category listings. Once I have this result set I then cache the object in Memcache and then use this cached object to set variables for the View to render the page.

This is all well and dandy however I am forced to do a `$this->redirect()` method once the cache has been set because otherwise my view variables are empty when the `view.ctp` is rendered. If a cache object already exists then I don't need to do the redirect because the variables are set immediately.

As my entire app relies on this third-party API I'm doing a lot of caching in Memcache and for the most part the app is behaving just normally with this redirect however I've hit an issue with a redirect loop when CakePHP is unable to set the cached object in Memcache as it simply runs through the code on each redirect with the same results.

Here is some code so you can better understand what is happening.

In my Categories controller I have the following view method:

```
public function view($cid, $loc, $page)
{
    $catCache = Cache::read('search_view_'.$cid.'_'.$loc.'_'.$page);
    if (!$catCache) {
        $url = Router::url(
            array(
                'controller' => 'Categories',
                'action' => 'saveCats',
                $page
            )
        );
        $this->requestAction($url);
        $this->redirect();
    }
    $this->set('view', $catCache);
}
```

This checks to see if a Memcache object already exists and if not I do a `$this->requestAction()` on the API method called `saveCats` that creates the cached object for me. Once this action has been performed I have to then call the redirect otherwise the `$view` variable data is empty. This is what that `saveCats` method looks like:

```
public function saveCats($page = null)
{
    if (is_null($page)) $page = 0;

    $cid = $this->request->data['Cat']['category'];
    $loc = $this->request->data['Cat']['region'];

    $address  = "http://api.url.com/".$cid;
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_POST => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $address,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'username:password'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options); 
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $filename = $content;
    $doc->loadXML($filename);

    $i = 0;
    while (is_object($view = $doc->getElementsByTagName('category')->item($i))) {
        foreach ($view->childNodes as $nodename) {
            if ($nodename->nodeName=='category:title') {
                $this->request->data['Browse'][$i]['title'] = h($nodename->nodeValue);
            }
            if ($nodename->nodeName=='category:description') {
                $this->request->data['Browse'][$i]['description'] = h($nodename->nodeValue);
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    Cache::write('search_view_'.$cid.'_'.$loc.'_'.$page, $this->request->data['Browse'], '2 hours');
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Finally, just for clarity sake, here is the `view.ctp` file that renders the content.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="cat_table">
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($view as $cat): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo h($cat['title']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo h($cat['description']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I essentially have two core issues here. The first is that I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong that forces me to have to use the `$this->redirect()` in order for CakePHP to set the `$view` variable correctly.

The second issue I have is the redirect loop issue which I could totally avoid if I didn't have to force this redirect. I've read some methods around potentially overcoming this using JavaScript however for this project I'm using absolutely zero JavaScript because it's targeted to devices that do not support JavaScript.

Any help on the above two issues is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a friend I have discovered where everything has been going wrong.

In order to avoid having to redirect, and in turn creating an infinite loop, you need to read the cache again after it has been set because the request action will set memcache but not read back into the catCache var.

```
public function view($cid, $loc, $page)
{
    $catCache = Cache::read('search_view_'.$cid.'_'.$loc.'_'.$page);
    if (!$catCache) {
        $url = Router::url(
            array(
                'controller' => 'Categories',
                'action' => 'saveCats',
                $page
            )
        );
        $this->requestAction($url);
        // Read the cache once the request action has been called
        $catCache = Cache::read('search_view_'.$cid.'_'.$loc.'_'.$page);
        // No need for the redirect now.
        // $this->redirect();
    }
    $this->set('view', $catCache);
}
```